# Google Oauth2 web sign-in from desktop application?

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I am developing a incremental backup desktop application using .NET4.5 that will backup user's local folder data into his/her own google drive.

I don't want the user to sign-in to google inside my desktop application (using OAuoth2). Like myself, users might not trust my application and may hesitate to provide their username and password into text input boxes native to my application. Embedding a browser control may not alleviate that trust-deficit either.

When user clicks a button in my application, I want to,

> 1. Open the default browser of user's desktop/laptop and take him/her to google's login page.
> 2. After user provides login credentials and okays the consent screen, the browser can close and my application comes to foreground.

I am not sure,

> 1. If this is a valid authentication scenario that is supported by OAUTH2.
> 2. If Yes, how to open a browser to [the Google Accounts authentication page](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?) and what key value to pass on so that google knows that this authentication is for a desktop application?
> 3. Upon end of user consent, how to get the code (provided by OAUTH2 server) inside my application? Once I get the code, I can carry on with subsequent OAUTH steps (acquiring access token, etc) via a web-control.

Appreciate any help on this. If this is a duplicate of a past query that I missed in my searches, please point me to that.

Answer (score 1):

[See OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Your use case matches the product description:

> an application can use OAuth 2.0 to obtain permission from users to
>   store files in their Google Drives.